# Residue field of composite of two field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

[image]
[image]

---

[Question]

I know that $K'\cdot K''$ is an unramified extension of $K$ but I don't know why $K'\cdot K''$ have a residue field $k'$.

is it always true that $K_1\cdot K_2$ have a residue field $k_1 \cdot k_2$?
(where $k_1,k_2$ are residue fields of $K_1, K_2$)

I think that if we prove the proposition 7.50 , then we can use " $K_1\cdot K_2$ have a residue field $k_1 \cdot k_2$" in this situation.

However, we can't use that fact while proving this proposition.

How can I prove this?

Thank you for your attention.

reference(J.S. Milne's *Algebraic Number Theory*) and this [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XDXV.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XDXV.png): [Strange reasoning of unramified extensions having same residue fields are the same.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165106/strange-reasoning-of-unramified-extensions-having-same-residue-fields-are-the-sa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ a finite extension then $F/K$ is unramified iff $F=K(\zeta_n)=K(\zeta_{q-1})$ with $p\nmid n$ and $q= |O_F/(\pi_F)|$. This is the main application of Hensel lemma.

When $E/K,E'/K$ are ramified then it is not always the case that the residue field of $EE'$  is the smallest field contained those of $E,E'$, try with $E=\Bbb{Q}_2(2^{1/3}),E'=\Bbb{Q}_2(\zeta_3 2^{1/3})$.

When $E'/K$ is unramified then $EE'=E(\zeta_{q-1})$ has residue field $O_E/(\pi_E)(\zeta_{q-1})$.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you something? If the base field is $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ ( not $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then still this hold?  (Maybe, you assumed that characteristic is $0$)

Comment: Also, is $n$  any natural number and $q$ prime number such that $p\nmid n$ and $q= |O_F/(\pi_F)|$ ?  
Then, you mean, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $F=K(\zeta_n)$.

Probably, it seems to be misunderstood. 
So, may I ask you the reference with proof of this "the main application of Hensel lemma" ?

Finally, I don't understand why this imply that $K'\cdot K''$ have a residue field $k'$.
Sorry and thank you.

Comment: It works the same way for finite extensions of $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$ and any complete discretely valued fields. Unramified means that $[F:K]=[O_F/(\pi_F):O_K/(\pi_K)]$, take a  generator of the residue field extension, lift its minimal polynomial to $O_K[x]$ which stays irreducible, Hensel lemma gives a root $a$ of it in $O_F$ then $[K(a):K]=[O_F/(\pi_F):O_K/(\pi_K)]$ thus $K(a)=F$.

Comment: $\zeta_{q-1}$ is when the residue field is finite.